# fetch data from user input

Tags: javascript, html

So i want the user to input a date into #dateUsetInput, then after they click the button i want the fetch function to grab that input and use it to fetch the appropiate image from that date.
But when i do that this error appears:

```
VM113:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at getimages (index.js:16:29)
getimages @ index.js:16
await in getimages (async)
(anonymous) @ index.js:12
```

This is the javascript code:

```
/*
i want user to input a date
if the date isnt valid put message 'message not valid';
get the date and put it into the fetch function
after that put the image on the screen along with the name of the rover
*/


const button = document.getElementById('updatePic')
button.addEventListener('onclick', getimages())

async function getimages(){
const response = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=${document.getElementById("dateUserInput").value}&api_key=rwX3pO8mONvdxngtstqSuNfwhrwMoGTy6clxqSnu`)
const data = await response.json()
}
```

and this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="index.js" defer></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="dateUserInput">
    <button type="button" id="updatePic">Update Picture</button>
<div class="roverImage"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

What is wrong and what can i do?

Comment: Does the API return an image or a JSON object. The error indicates there is an error in the JSON returned

Comment: Is that your real API key? You shouldn't post that in a public forum.

Comment: `getimages()` should be `getimages()` in the call to `addEventListener()`. You're calling the function immediately, not when the user clicks the button.

Comment: The API URL provide, if it's correct, isn't actually working. So, you need to double check that API is working

Comment: And `onclick` should just be `click`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the API with an empty input value when the page is first loaded, not when the user clicks on the button.

The first argument to `addEventListener` is an event name. `onclick` is not an event, it's an HTML attribute name that corresponds to the `click` event.

The second argument must be a function. You're calling the function, not passing a reference to the function.

```
const button = document.getElementById('updatePic')
button.addEventListener('click', getimages)

async function getimages() {
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?earth_date=${document.getElementById("dateUserInput").value}&api_key=rwX3pO8mONvdxngtstqSuNfwhrwMoGTy6clxqSnu`)
  const data = await response.json()
}
```